# Is there anyway to make resolution settings using AS3 in Animate CC?

Tags: actionscript-3, screen-resolution, animate-cc

I have a project that needs to be made in Animate CC using ActionScript3. 
The situation is that I have to make resolution options, meaning that if I select a button it will change the resolution of my project to said resolution like 800x600 etc. Like video games you know.

i've tried using

```
    res1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setRes1);

    function setRes1(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        stage.fullScreenSourceRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 800, 600);
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to work, is there even a way to do this?

Comment: The **fullScreenSourceRect** property does not physically change the screen resolution (due to security reasons Flash Player is not allowed to fully control the display) but rather sets a rectangular area to scale to the screen while in fullscreen mode.

Comment: So meaning there isnt a way to implement that feature?

Comment: If you want to control the display and change its resolution, then no, Flash cannot do that.

Comment: Alright then, thank you!

Comment: Yes you can using ScreenMode class in AIR.

Answer (score 0):

Not using the Flash Player, but If you target AIR yes you can do it accessing the properties of NativeWindow. Stage.fullScreenSourceRect is read-only. But you can modify application size accessing NativeApplication.nativeApplication.nativeWindow.width = ...; This will not modify your pc screen resolution, but only resize the application window. You can change resolution in AIR though using the ScreenMode class. Detailed working is described here: https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/release-note/fp_31_air_31_release_notes.html#ScreenModeConfigurationforAIRDesktop